DNS Resolution Issue between Step Function and OpenSearch Domain in VPC Environment
I'm seeking assistance with troubleshooting an issue in my workflow. I have a step function that involves multiple steps to establish internal roles for an OpenSearch cluster and subsequently map them to IAM roles. This process includes calling a third-party API endpoint.
Initially, everything functioned correctly when tested in a sandbox environment with OpenSearch deployed outside of the VPC. However, I'm currently facing a challenge as I attempt to test it within a scenario where the OpenSearch cluster resides inside our VPC. Consequently, I've set up a custom VPC endpoint for the Step Function.
However, I've encountered an issue wherein I receive the following message: "field resolves to a forbidden IP Address: []".
For clarity, the OpenSearch cluster employs fine-grained access control, without any resource-based policy that would restrict access to the domain. The Step Function role is configured as an administrator, granting it all necessary privileges.
Both the OpenSearch cluster and the VPC endpoint are situated on the same subnet, which is privately configured with egress. The outbound rules for the VPC endpoint and inbound rules for OpenSearch are appropriately configured.
I have conducted DNS resolution checks from our bastion host, which returned successful results. Consequently, it seems that the issue lies specifically with DNS resolution between the step function and the OpenSearch domain.
Any assistance or insights would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your attention and support.
I configured a custom VPC endpoint for my Step Function to access an OpenSearch cluster within my VPC. I expected the Step Function to resolve the OpenSearch domain properly, as DNS resolution from the bastion host worked. However, I encountered an issue where the Step Function reported "field resolves to a forbidden IP Address" for the OpenSearch domain.

Step Functions cannot connect directly into your VPC. The VPC Endpoints for Step Functions allow you to call the Step Functions service from inside the VPC (without using NAT etc. to route outside your VPC), but not for Step Functions to initiate calls out into your VPC. This is a need we hear from a lot of customers and something we will explore further in the future, but at this point, it's not supported.
Your best bet is likely to use a Lambda function as an intermediary. You can deploy the Lambda function into the VPC and make calls to the Open Search API using the AWS SDK. You can then invoke that Lambda function from your State Machine.
